# Error 683: "Specified STEP expression will not traverse RANGE" when selecting from view

Tags: informix

I have a view in Informix 12.10 (Linux x86_64) defined like this.

```
create view "dbo".perinexv
(
   ac0,   ri0,   wf0,   up0,   di0,   dp0,   if0,   iu0,   ts0,   dv0,   dc0,   ca0,   m0,   ax0,   ce0,   al0,   tg0,   ti0,   tf0,   tn0,   pu0,   tr0,   fm0,   pq0,   av0,   ad0,   ab0,   af0,   an0,   ct0,   et0,   ft0,   fn0,   nb0,   pi0,   hb0,   rx0,   rz0,   az0,   as0,    dr0,   ii0,   xr0,   le0,   sk0,   sl0,   wd0
)
as
select
('SK' || x1.kat_c ) ::varchar(8),
'PE' ::char(2),
CASE WHEN ((x0.dat_zru < CURRENT year to month ) OR ((x0.dat_zru IS NULL ) AND (((mod(x0.vestzru,100 ) - YEAR (TODAY ) ) < 0. ) OR ((mod(x0.vestzru,100 ) - YEAR (TODAY ) ) > 20. ) ) ) ) THEN '.' ELSE ' ' END ::char(1),
CASE WHEN (x0.dat_zru < (CURRENT year to month - interval( 1) month(9) to month ) ) THEN 'H' WHEN (x0.dat_zru < CURRENT year to month ) THEN 'W' WHEN (x1.datzv < (CURRENT year to month - interval( 1) month(9) to month ) ) THEN ('U' || CASE WHEN EXISTS (select x5.datzv from "dbo".evuknor x5 where ((((x5.datzv < CURRENT year to month ) AND (x5.zmop != '1' ) ) AND (x5.identif = x0.identif ) ) AND (x5.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) ) THEN '*M' ELSE '  ' END ) ELSE ('N' || CASE WHEN EXISTS (select x6.datzv from "dbo".evuknor x6 where ((((x6.datzv < CURRENT year to month ) AND (x6.zmop != '1' ) ) AND (x6.identif = x0.identif ) ) AND (x6.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) ) THEN '*M' ELSE '  ' END ) END ::char(3),
TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x0.identif ) ::varchar(50),
x1.datzv ::date,
CASE WHEN (x0.identif NOT MATCHES ((((('*' || LPAD (x0.cistn,2,'0' )) || ' ' ) || x0.cisskn ) || LPAD (x0.cisnsk,2,'0' )) || '*' ) ) THEN (((LPAD (x0.cistn,2,'0' )|| ' ' ) || x0.cisskn ) || LPAD (x0.cisnsk,2,'0' )) END ::char(7),
'Normalization office' ::varchar(128),
'ST*N' ::char(4),
x1.datuc ::date,
x1.datsch ::date,
(select informix.concagr(TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x7.ics ),'*' ) ::varchar(64) from "dbo".charcsn x7 where ((x7.identif = x0.identif ) AND (x7.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) ) ::varchar(64),
((('TK ' || x2.cistnk ) || ' ' ) || x2.nametnk ::varchar(255) ),
NULL ::date,
NULL ::char(1),
x1.jazyk ::char(2),
NULL ::char(1),
REPLACE (x3.nazang,'|','/' )::char(440),
NULL ::char(1),
REPLACE (x0.nazevn,'|','/' )::char(440),
'UNMS SR' ::varchar(24),
NULL ::char(1),
NVL ((x1.str_celk || CASE WHEN (x1.format != 'A4' ) THEN ('/' || x1.format ) ELSE '' END ),'not applicable' )::varchar(14),
(x4.cena_kc || ' EUR' ::varchar(13) ),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
rmnl(REPLACE (x3.abstr,'|','/' ))::lvarchar(2046),
NULL ::char(1),
(select informix.concagr(TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x9.heslo ),'*' ) ::lvarchar(2046) from "dbo".deskrcsn x8,"dbo".klicslo x9 where (((((x8.identif = x0.identif ) AND (x8.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) AND (x8.isoroot = x9.isoroot ) ) AND (x9.jazyk = 'en' ) ) AND (x9.heslo > '' ) ) ) ::lvarchar(2046),
NULL ::char(1),
(select informix.concagr(TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x11.heslo ),'*' ) ::lvarchar(2046) from "dbo".deskrcsn x10,"dbo".klicslo x11 where (((((x10.identif = x0.identif ) AND (x10.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) AND (x10.isoroot = x11.isoroot ) ) AND (x11.jazyk = 'sk' ) ) AND (x11.heslo > '' ) ) ) ::lvarchar(2046),
rmnl(REPLACE (x0.pozncsn,'|','/' ))::varchar(255),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
(select informix.concagr((((TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x13.identif ) || '(' ) || REPLACE (LPAD (x13.rokvyd ::varchar(7),7,'0' ),'.','-' )) || ')' ),'*' ) ::lvarchar(2046) from "dbo".zmena x12,"dbo".evuknor x13 where (((((x12.kat_c = x13.kat_c ) AND (x12.identif = x0.identif ) ) AND (x12.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) AND (x12.zmzr IN ('0','S' )) ) AND (x12.rokvyd > 1900.00 ) ) ) ::lvarchar(2046),
(select informix.concagrl((((TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x14.identif ) || '(' ) || REPLACE (LPAD (x14.rokvyd ::varchar(7),7,'0' ),'.','-' )) || ')' ),'*' ) ::lvarchar(4094) from "dbo".zmena x14 where (((x14.kat_c = x1.kat_c ) AND (x14.zmzr IN ('0','S' )) ) AND (x14.rokvyd > 1900.00 ) ) ) ::lvarchar(4094),
(select informix.concagr((((x15.zmop || ' ' ) || TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x15.idzm ) ) || NVL ((' ' || LPAD (REPLACE ((x15.vestnik / 100.0000000000000000 ) ::decimal(4,2),'.','/' ),5,'0' )),'' )),'*' ) from "dbo".evuknor x15 where ((((x15.identif = x0.identif ) AND (x15.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd ) ) AND (x15.zmop != '1' ) ) AND (x15.datzv < CURRENT year to month ) ) ) ::varchar(255),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
(select informix.concagr(((((CASE WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'E' ) THEN 'eqv' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'H' ) THEN 'har' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'I' ) THEN 'idt' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'M' ) THEN 'mod' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'N' ) THEN 'neq' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'O' ) THEN 'idt' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'R' ) THEN 'rel' WHEN (x16.stupshod = 'Z' ) THEN 'zap' ELSE NVL (x16.stupshod ::char(3),'   ' ) END || ' ' ) || TRIM ( BOTH ' ' FROM x17.identzn ) ) || ':' ) || x17.rokvzn ),'*' ) from "dbo".prevzeti x16,"dbo".meznorm x17 where ((x16.kat_c = x1.kat_c ) AND (x16.xmezn = x17.xmezn ) ) ) ::varchar(255),
NULL ::char(1),
NULL ::char(1),
(CASE WHEN (x0.dat_zru < CURRENT year to month ) THEN 'Z' ELSE 'A' END || sortkey(x0.identif )::varchar(50) ),
NULL ::char(1),
x0.dat_zru ::date
from "dbo".csn x0,
"dbo".evuknor x1,
outer("dbo".tnk x2 ),
outer("dbo".csntext x3 ),
outer("dbo".censkup x4 )
where
(
   (
      (
         (
            (
               (
                  (
                     ((x0.rokvyd > 1900.00 ) AND (x1.zmop = '1' ) )
                     AND (x1.datzv < CURRENT year to month )
                  )
                  AND (x1.identif = x0.identif )
               )
               AND (x1.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd )
            )
            AND (x0.cistnk = x2.cistnk )
         )
         AND (x3.identif = x0.identif )
      )
      AND (x3.rokvyd = x0.rokvyd )
   )
   AND (x4.censk = x1.censk )
)
;
```

When I run the command `select count(ac0) from perinexv`, it gives me correct results

```
> select count(ac0) from perinexv;


         (count)

           71476

1 row(s) retrieved.
```

But when I try to run `select count(*) from perinexv` I receive error 683.

```
> select count(*) from perinexv;

  683: Specified STEP expression will not traverse RANGE.
Error in line 1
Near character position 28
```

If I run `select ac0 from perinexv` the output is correct

```
> select ac0 from perinexv;


ac0

SK68386
SK68387
...
SK136374
SK136375

71476 row(s) retrieved.
```

It is also correct for each separate column. No error is returned.
The error 683 means:

**683 Specified STEP expression will not traverse RANGE.**
*The evaluated value of the STEP expression in the FOR statement will lead to an infinite loop.*
Example of error:
*FOR i = 10 TO 20 STEP -1; — error … END FOR*
Correction: *Correct either the range or the step expressions so that the incremented values are within the range.*

I don't see any step function in the view definition, also, when I try to select each column separately it is without errors.

When I limited the number of rows returned, e.g. `select first 100 * from perinexv` and it works OK up to about 20000, but sure, when I add sorting (`order by ca0`), it fails with the error above.
When I run the `select * from perinexv`, it always finishes with the same ac0 value, so it seems like an issue in the data. Is there any way how to find the following row of the result?
Do you have any other idea what can cause the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages, but more importantly, read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)
 — the same idea by a different name).  For SQL-related questions, please follow the advice on the [SQL Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info).  Minimize the complexity of the SQL and provide enough schema that we can reproduce the problem with the info you give.

Comment: Not sure but that view seems to be using some user made aggregates: "concagr", "concagrl". It is possible that the FOR instructions are being used on those aggregates.

Comment: Thank you, @LuísMarques, you are right. It was one of the functions in the view definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue identified. It was an issue with data.

In view `perinexv` there is column `sk0` with the following definition:

```
(CASE WHEN (x0.dat_zru < CURRENT year to month ) THEN 'Z' ELSE 'A' END || sortkey(x0.identif )::varchar(50) )
```

There is a function `sortkey()` and parameter `x0.identif` (`x0` is table `evuknor` in this case).
In definition of the `sortkey()` the following FOR loop can be found:

```
LET txt = TRIM(txt);
FOR posa=1 TO LENGTH(txt) STEP 1
 IF SUBSTR(txt,posa,1)=' ' THEN
  LET txt = SUBSTR(txt,posa);
  EXIT FOR;
 END IF
END FOR
```

As you can see, when the `LENGTH(txt)` (where `txt` consists of a value of `x0.identif`) is equal to 0 (empty string), the error I mentioned appears.

Unfortunately, the empty string value exists in the source table and it caused this issue.

The solution is to add the missing value to the source table and change the column definition to not allow empty strings.